# Is there any way to run a .jar file directly from a java Unix executable?

Tags: macos, unix, java

I have a `.jar` file and would like to open it using a Unix executable, `java`, that I have embedded within another application.(I do not have Java installed for security reasons) Is there any way to run this `.jar` file on OS X, directly using the Unix executable, preferably without requiring that Terminal, iTerm, etc must remain open? I know that running `path/to/java -jar file.jar` runs the `.jar` file just fine, but the Terminal window must remain open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can `nohup /path/to/java -jar /path/to/server.jar &` on other Unix/Linux systems. I just tried it and did not have any luck with OSX.

You can run it in a screen session.

```
screen -S ScreenSessionName -dmS /path/to/java -jar file.jar
```

You can reattach to screen to stop or change setting on the running program with

```
screen -r ScreenSessionName
```

Type `man screen` in the terminal for more information on how the screen utility can be used.